# kalman filter in detecting circle

Tags: object-detection, ros, kalman-filter

I am using HoughCircles to detect the position of the circle(the images are from the camera of the UAV ), but the position coordinates of the center of the circle and the radius of the circle are disturbed by Gaussian noise,so i want to use the kalman filter to remove the noise,but the question is can i use the kalman filter of one dimension to process the position (including x,y) and radius severally? is this way is equal to predict the circle with a more complicated kalman filter?

the images are from the camera of the UAV, so it is a little hard to describe the circles position in the image

Comment: Kalman filtering is not constrained to 1d state. Just use the general algorithm. The bigger question is why you think Kalman filtering is appropriate. It's normally used when a system dynamic behavior model is available (e.g. Newtonian response), inputs affecting the model are known perfectly, and sensors of the current model state are noisy. It provides an estimate of the true model state that's optimal under certain conditions. You haven't described model state or inputs. Perhaps you want something simpler like a Gaussian filter.